# Why cython not found?

Tags: python, deb

I'm trying to build deb files with obs([open build service](https://openbuildservice.org/)), however, when I excute `osc build --local-package`, I got the error as below:

```
[  269s] make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/packages/BUILD'
[  269s] cython --cplus msgpack/*.pyx
[  269s] /bin/sh: 1: cython: not found
[  269s] Makefile:7: recipe for target 'cython' failed
[  269s] make[1]: *** [cython] Error 127
[  269s] make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/packages/BUILD'
[  269s] dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
[  269s] debian/rules:18: recipe for target 'build' failed
[  269s] make: *** [build] Error 2
[  269s] dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

It seems that /bin/sh doesn't found cython. while cython is install in my ubuntu.

```
$ which cython
/usr/bin/cython
$ cython --version
Cython version 0.23.4
```

Can anyone help me?
thanks